# Limiting Fields in Django 1.8

Tags: python, django

I have the following `models.py`

```
class Rockinfo(models.Model):
    rock_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="ac/dc")
    rock_img = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/",default="1992/08/92")
    rank = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=1000,default="they are the best")


def __str__(self):              
    return self.rock_name

class Rockvids(models.Model):
    rockername = models.ForeignKey(Rockinfo)
    vid_id1 = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="Z7JgY9zezj4")
    vid_id2 = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="TABgNerEro8")

def __str__(self):
    return self.vid_id1
```

And `admin.py`

```
class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Rockvids
    extra = 10
```

This should allow me to add 10 instances of `vid_id1` and `vid_id2` in django admin. But what it does is, everytime I add the 10 fields, and save it in the django admin, it adds 10 more fields(with the default values) everytime I try to edit it.And then those extra videos with their default values also get displayed. Is there a way to restrict it to only 10 values in the admin and in the template.

Comment: Doesn't [`max_num`](/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.max_num) do the job?

Comment: Yeah it does.Didn't know about it.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
model = Rockvids
extra = 10
max_num = 10
```

This limits the number of instances.